# Which one matters more - grades or qualifications - for admission to post-graduate study in Germany?

Tags: masters, funding, germany, gpa, statistics

I'm looking into applying to study abroad in Germany after my Bachelors (majoring in Statistics). My question is:
which of these hypothetical candidates would have a higher chance at receiving a scholarship and being accepted in a Masters program?

1- Someone studying in a top university with good qualifications required for the course, including German skills, English skills, knowledge about their field of study etc. but with a less than appealing GPA

or

2- Someone studying in a mediocre university with mediocre qualifications but a high GPA

Comment: There is too little known about the "candidates" to make any reasonable judgement. If you are one or the other you need to explain and account for any deficiencies. And everyone's definition of a "mediocre university" will be different.

Comment: I usually base my opinions about a university's "mediocrity" on the global or national rankings which, I know, aren't very credible but can be a way to help differentiate between the quality of education. But I think it makes sense that these factors aren't enough to judge the candidates - thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Buffy: *"If you are one or the other you need to explain and account for any deficiencies."* In some situations, yes, but not necessarily. There are many Master's programmes at German universities where you are automatically admitted if you earned a Bachelor's degree in the same field with a certain grade (and for some of these programmes this minimum grade need not be particularly good). In this case, nobody will ask the applicant to explain or account for any deficiencies at all.

Comment: @JochenGlueck ... though the universities have "translation tables" for grades, which depend on where you got your grade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're specifically asking about the situation in Germany, here are a few remarks that might be interesting for you (although the main point of these remarks is that it is essentially impossible to answer the question at the given level of generality).

- Admission rules at German universities depend on various things: for instance, the specific university/universities you're applying to, your intended field of study, and the specific programme(s) your applying to. Also, admissions for scholarships will strongly depend on the particular scholarship(s) you're applying for.
- Things might also depend a lot on whether you are a citizen of a country within the European Union. Some (but certainly not all) Master programmes in Germany have quite loose and simple rules of admission for German citizens and thus, by EU regulations, also for EU citizens. For instance, for many Master programmes in mathematics, a Bachelor's degree in mathematics with a certain grade will suffice for admission.

  (But one important issue here is, of course, how grades will be converted between different academic systems.)

  On the other hand, things can be more complicated (and more expensive, by the way) for international students from outside the EU.
- Concerning the "top university vs. mediocre university" stuff: Generally speaking, prestige of universities plays a much smaller role in the German academic system than, for instance, in the US (even if an applicant has done their undergraduate studies in a country where such prestige questions play a huge role, chances are that this won't be weighted as much in the decision process at a German university as the applicant might expect).

  But then again, as pointed out above, things depend a lot on the particular circumstances, and there is at least a non-zero chance that such prestige questions *might* play a certain role in the admission process. For some programmes that are specifically designed for international students, it can even happen that private agencies are involved in the admission process and, for instance, make a recommendation on whether an applicant should be admitted or not. Whether such agencies take the purported prestige (or ranking) of universities into account will, again, depend on various circumstances.

  As a corollary of the cultural aspect described above, I should probably add the following point: In case that the application process includes the submission of a cover letter or a statement of purpose or a personal interview (which might be more likely for applications to scholarships than for applications to study programmes - but again, it probably depends), my advice would be to be a bit careful in case that you're in situation 1) described in the question. If your application leaves the impression "My grades haven't been good so far, but my degree is from a top university, which certainly makes up for the bad grades", there's a considerable probability that this attitude will backfire.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that there very few scholarships exist compared to other countries.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not an EU resident so it will be much more difficult for me.

Comment: I specifically asked about the university's "quality" because I had my pick between a low tier university where they just hand you grades and a top university where you would be challenged. I picked the top university and now I'm worried about what it means for my future. I certainly don't rely on the fact that my university would be considered "good" because what matters is how educated I ultimately become. I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote but this was very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: There is a good chance you will get accepted in a German masters program, as there are plenty of good universities in Germany. Whether it will be the one you were initially hoping for is another question, but that is true everywhere. So, don't worry about things you can no longer change, and start applying. That is the only way to get an answer that truly matters.

Comment: @Feiznia: Even the "top" universities often only have some (very attainable) fixed cutoff GPA requirement for their masters degrees. Or not even that. Some will invite you to an interview if there's doubt but in general getting into most programs is fairly trivial if you meet the formal requirements (i.e. took the right courses and have "good enough" grades).

Comment: @Peter: Yes, this is certainly true for many of the "standard" Master's degrees. On the other hand, many German universities now also have some programmes which are specifically designed to attract international students, and for some of these courses, admission requirements are sometimes a bit different (though this is probably not always the case).

Comment: @MaartenBuis This gives me so much hope! I have a few universities in mind but I'm not too picky given the circumstances. It might be worth mentioning that I'm still a freshman so I'm planning way ahead, however I can't help but to worry. Regardless, I genuinely appreciate your response.

Comment: @Peter I've heard about the interview but I was worried if they would see someones application and immediately ignore it after seeing they don't have a very high GPA.

Comment: @JochenGlueck You're right, I've seen programs and scholarships meant for international students and students from developing countries. I guess those would be my best bet!